# Do I have to call get() on the future returned by TaskQueue's addAsync()?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using an experimental feature of Java App Engine that was released in 1.7.6 that does async task queue operations.

The documentation for that is here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview#asynchronous-operations

My question is, do I have to call get() on the returned future when doing TaskQueue.addAsync(), or is it pretty much guaranteed that addAsync() will add the task to the queue just like add()?

For example, what happens if an incoming HTTP request does an addAsync() of one or more tasks and the request completes and I never call get()? Any information on this would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/#Java_Asynchronous_operations) says that you should indeed call `get()`:

> When asynchronously adding tasks in a transaction, you should call `get()` on the Future before committing the transaction to ensure that the request has finished.

It's not clear whether you should also do this if you don't do this in a transaction but it's probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: What's the point in using `addAsync(...)` if you then have to call `get()`? You may as well just use `add(...)`. That said, I suppose you could queue a load of stuff with `addAsync(...)` and then wait for completion of all of them.